# Does really a spring compresses placed between two blocks when one block is given force on a frictionless surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, friction, potential-energy, spring

When Spring is placed between two bodies on a frictionless surface it gets compressed when one block is given kinetic energy as told by my physics teacher. But it should not compress as there's no opposite force which produces squeezing effect on Spring.     Does really Spring compresses or not and reason please.

Answer (score 1):

The system is subject to a non-zero net force in the horizontal direction and no friction, so it will experience constant acceleration (of the center of mass). Superimposed on that motion with be the anti-symmetric oscillation of the two masses on the spring.

If the masses are both $m$ and the spring is characterized by constant $k$ the angular frequency of oscillation will be $\omega=\sqrt{2k/m}$. (It's $2k$ because the motion is anti-symmetric which is much like each block oscillating on half the spring.) If the spring is light compared to the masses the overall acceleration will be $F/(2m)$.

---

The reason the spring compresses initially (and thereby sets the oscillation in motion is that the block on the other end has inertia, and it can only start accelerating as a force develops in the spring. But that happens as the first mass moves toward the second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. The spring behaves like friction here. When the first block is pushed, it transfers the energy to the spring which converts the kinetic energy to its potential energy.  Once the second block overcomes its inertia, it will also start to move.

Think of two blocks on a surface with friction without a spring in between. Pushing the first block doesn't make both the blocks move until the force exceeds the friction force.

The spring in the first scenario is exactly like that. You can even try this at home on a smooth surface and see it happen.

Comment: *"Only when the spring is fully compressed does it transfer the energy to the second block."* I don't think that's true at all. The moment the spring gets compressed it starts pushing on the second block. Although it experiences inertia, the second block will start moving right away.

Comment: You might be right. Let me go refresh my understanding of springs.

Comment: Take a spring that's attached to a wall and compress it. Will it exert a force on that wall? Of course.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm just a bit rusty with my mechanicst. That's what I get for trying to solve mechanics problems after 7 years.

Comment: Let me edit my answer

Comment: Gert this is satisfying answer from "first comment" of yours. Thanks for removing my confusion.